# Crash when using Double? property in SQLIte in Blazor Wasm (.Net6)

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I'm using Blazor Wasm with a SQLite clientdatabase. Like here (https://github.com/dotnetnoobie/BlazorAppSqlite)

```
public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; } = default!;
.....
public class Test
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double? NullableDoubleValue { get; set; }
}
......
var test = new Test();
test.Id = 1;
test.NullableDoubleValue = 1;

_appState.ClientSideDbContext.Tests.Add(test);
 await _appState.ClientSideDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

When the last line is executed, the Blazor app wil crash.
With this error in the log:
/__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/mini/aot-runtime-wasm.c:113 
/__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/mini/aot-runtime-wasm.c:113 
Uncaught ExitStatus

What change do I have to make to use a (nullable) double?

Comment: Is trimming enabled? EF Core doesn't currently support trimming. (See [dotnet/efcore#21894](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21894))

Comment: @bricelam Is there a workaround until then? I've tried `<IsTrimmable>false</IsTrimmable>` and `<PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>` on my .csproj.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to come from using float or double. The fix has been merged and it will probably be released with dotnet 7 [as mentioned in this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67970).

> Description
>
> Seeing a bug when using SQLitePCL.Raw preview and also see the same bug in Steve Sandersons Blaze Orbital sample when using double/float in entity classes. Works fine with decimals! Tried with EF Core and SQLite-net.

As a workaround, you can use decimal instead of float or double and it will work just fine.